# Getting Error -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, request

I want to get data from the Book API but when I search I get the error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`.

```
{Array.isArray(resData) &&
    resData.map(
      (item, index) =>
        index < 7 && (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <BooksList
              id={item.id}
              title={item.volumeInfo.title}
              authors={item.volumeInfo.authors}
              categories={item.volumeInfo.categories}
              image={item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}
              description={item.volumeInfo.description}
              language={item.volumeInfo.language}
              pages={item.volumeInfo.pageCount}
            />
          </li>
        )
    )}
```

Here's the requesting API:

```js
const searchClickHandler = async () => {
  const searchKey = searchedValue;
  const reqURL = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${searchKey}&key=${apiKey}`;

  const response = await fetch(reqURL);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw json({ message: "Could not fetch the data" }, { status: 500 });
  }

  const responseData = await response.json();
  setResData(responseData.items);
};
console.log(resData);
```

I am expecting the array response that contains book data but I want to print only minimum of 7 items or response array length items but I get the error above, although response array length is more then 10.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You're trying to do `something.map(/*...*/)` where `something` is `undefined`. Please [**search thoroughly**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+Cannot+read+properties+of+undefined) before posting, this topic is very well covered by previous questions and their answers.

Comment: Thank you for putting the code in the question as text. But the error you've quoted clearly won't happen in the code you've shown, so this error must be coming from somewhere **else** (probably something in `BooksList`). The error message has a link to where the error occurred, that's what you need to debug.